Lock Tracking in Word Using the Word JavaScript API
I am currently working with the Word JavaScript API, and I can enable Track Changes for the following document
 await Word.run(async (context) => {
      const document = context.document;
      document.load("changeTrackingMode");
      await context.sync();
      document.changeTrackingMode = Word.ChangeTrackingMode.trackAll;
    });

. However, when I enable it, it can still be turned off directly in Word. Is there a way for me to lock it, similar to Lock Tracking?
I cannot find any documentation regarding Lock Tracking.
